# Why is this handler method(/trying) returning the error 404 instead of sending the request to another handler method /addpage

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping("/trying")
public String trying(){

return "/addpage";

}
```

> "/addpage" is a request handler method used for handling a request....... But when I try returning "/addpage" from the handler method "/trying" I get the error 404.

How can I solve this...

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't add code as images as those are unreadable. Please add your full controller **as code** and explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: If you want to invoke another controler you need to redirect to it so you would need to return `redirect:/addpage` instead of `/addpage`. The latter would try to render a view named `/addpage.jsp` or whatever you choose a a view technology.

Comment: Yeah.... It worked that way.... But in another project I I didn't use the redirect neither did I instantiate a new view technology... But it worked, so I'm guessing if there's something I did wrong....

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you project is compiling correctly : mvn clean install
2. The server is starting without errors
3. remove the "/" to "/addpage" ==> you do not need it if you dont have a path to put other wise  ==> "path/to/folder/addpage"

Comment: That won't help as 1 and 2 are already in place and 3 will render a page not redirect to a controller.